# How to show the hashtag count from Twitter on a web page

Tags: javascript, twitter, gulp, hashtag

I am trying to figure out the best way to show the count of a specific hashtag from Twitter on a web page. I assumed this would be a fairly easy task, but I am running into a little confusion. The goal ultimately is to show the count when the page loads. It does not have to be dynamic, just run the request when the page loads.

Ive got a Twitter Dev account, but I dont see how to grab the hash count anywhere in the docs.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs

I also found this: https://github.com/cstephen/hashtag-count which is doing what I want, but via npm. I don't know how I would take that object from a gulpfile to vanilla javascript to show it in html. Also, having it in gulp would mean I would need to setup a runner on the server.

So far Ive got this:

**The gulp path:**

```
var hc = new HashtagCount({
  'consumer_key': '...',
  'consumer_secret': '...',
  'access_token': '...',
  'access_token_secret': '...'
});

// Array of hashtags to tally. Do not include # prefix.
var hashtags = ['superbowl', 'pizza', 'beer'];

// Hashtag tallies for each time interval will be added to the results object.
var interval = '30 seconds';

// Delete data older than this.
var history = '5 minutes';

// Called at the end of each time interval.
var intervalCb = function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(results);
  }
};

// Open a connection to Twitter's Streaming API and start capturing tweets!
hc.start({
  hashtags: hashtags,       // required
  interval: interval,       // required
  history: history,         // optional
  intervalCb: intervalCb,   // optional
});
```

If I go this route,

A: How do I get this object into javascript, to show the integer in html?

B: How would I set this up on a server to run the gulp task incrementally?

Am I missing a simpler solution?

**UPDATE**
[image]

Ive got the npm exmaple version working. I just need to get that data from Gulp to html.

**My html so far**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hashtag Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Total Hashtag Count</h1>
    <p id="hashCount">Replace this string with the hashtag count</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is 'count of a specific hashtag'?

Comment: I would like to render on the web page the number of times a specific hashtag has been used.

Answer (score 0):

If you read further down the github page you will find [Result object](https://github.com/cstephen/hashtag-count#results-object)

Results object

The results object has the same structure regardless of whether it appears in the intervalCb or finishedCb callbacks. It takes the following form, where the time stamp is an ISO string in UTC time representing the beginning of each interval:

```
{
  '2017-01-16T00:00:10.606Z': { 'superbowl': 6, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 8 },
  '2017-01-16T00:01:10.610Z': { 'superbowl': 7, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 4 },
  '2017-01-16T00:02:10.612Z': { 'superbowl': 3, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 0 }
}
```

Knowing that we can use it in the results section like this

```
// Called at the end of each time interval.
var intervalCb = function (err, results) {
  if (err) {

    console.error(err);

  } else {

    console.log( results );

    showHashTagsCount( twitterResults );
  }
};
```

With all the informations, here is an example function :

```js
const twitterResults = {
  '2017-01-16T00:00:10.606Z': { 'superbowl': 6, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 8 },
  '2017-01-16T00:01:10.610Z': { 'superbowl': 7, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 4 },
  '2017-01-16T00:02:10.612Z': { 'superbowl': 3, 'pizza': 1, 'beer': 0 }
};

function showHashTagsCount ( results )
{
  let totalTagsCount = 
    // Get the tags name and count from results
    Object.values( results ).map( hashTags => {
      
      // Get the tags count from hashTags and reduce to get the total
      return Object.values( hashTags ).reduce( ( acc, tagCount ) => acc + tagCount, 0 );
    
    // Reduce to get the total tags count
    }).reduce( ( acc, tagsCount ) => acc + tagsCount, 0 );
  
  // Show hash tags count
  document.getElementById( 'hashCount' ).textContent = totalTagsCount;
}

// Usage example
showHashTagsCount( twitterResults );
```

```html
<h1>Total Hashtag Count</h1>
<p id="hashCount">Replace this string with the hashtag count</p>
```

Comment: That object is in the gulpfile. How would I pull that into the DOM to render via html on the client side?

Comment: There isnt enough information about your project structure to answer that.

Comment: Right now, my project structure is an index.html page. Ive got an assets folder where Ive got css and javascript. Thats about it.

Comment: Ok but where do you wish to show those informations ? In an existing element on your page ? By adding them dynamically ? We dont have any information about this...

Comment: Added my html file. The idea wouldbe to hook that <p> element via ID and replace  the text with the number.